# Attach MethodCallExpression to Property/Parameter

Tags: c#, .net, lambda, linq-expressions

I have the following MethodCallExpression:

```
{Party.Any(party => party.Address.Any(address => address.Line1.Contains("Address 1")))}
```

I need it attached to a parent level Property/Parameter so that the final lambda looks like:

```
{txliferequest => txliferequest.OLifE.Party.Any(party => party.Address.Any(address => address.Line1.Contains("Address 1")))}
```

The original MethodCallExpression is passed into an extension method so I am attempting to append the final lambda structure.

---

**TXLifeRequest**

```
public partial class TXLifeRequest : BaseEntity
{
    public virtual OLifE OLifE { get; set; }

    ...
}
```

---

**OLifE**

```
public partial class OLifE : BaseEntity
{
    public virtual List<Party> Party { get; set; }
        ...
}
```

---

**Party**

```
public class Party: BaseEntity
{
    public virtual List<Address> Address { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

I am attempting to attach is as a property accessor but am not sure how to do that.  Here is what I'm attempting:

```
//{Name = "OLifE" FullName = "IMSParamed.Entities.OLifE"}
Type parentBaseType = parentPropInfo.GetListBaseType();

//{IMSParamed.Entities.OLifE OLifE}
PropertyInfo propInfo = parentBaseType.GetParentMappedPropertyInfo();

//{OLifE}
ParameterExpression parentTypeParam2 = parentPropInfo.Name.ToParameter(parentBaseType);

//{OLifE.Party}
MemberExpression typeProp = type.Name.ToProperty(parentTypeParam2);

//Type lambdaType = typeof(Func<,>).MakeGenericType(type, typeof(bool));

MethodInfo anyMethod = ExpressionBuilder.anyTSource.MakeGenericMethod(type);

//{OLifE.Party.Any(party => party.Address.Any(address => address.Line1.Contains("Address 1")))}
MethodCallExpression any = Expression.Call(anyMethod, typeProp, methodCallExp);
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: I'm guessing I have to reconstruct the MethodCallExpression with the correct parameter chain.